# How do you instantiate an Array of Arrays without a null entry?

Tags: typescript, angular7

I've got an array of arrays as follows:

```
namesByGroup: [string[]];
```

I then populate this with arrays of names like this (feel free to suggest ways to improve this code as well):

```
private setNamesByGroup() {
  let groupNames = [];
  this.namesByGroup = [[]]; //This is where it's adding an empty array at the start of the namesByGroup array.

  this.groups.forEach(group => {
    var nameIds = Object.keys(group.nameData);

    nameIds.forEach(id => {
      let nameDetails = <NameDetail>this._keyValuePipe.transform(group.nameData).find(kvp => kvp == id).value;
      groupNames.push(nameDetails.name);
    };

    this.namesByGroup.push(groupNames);
    groupNames = [];
  }
}
```

This adds an empty string array at the start of `namesByGroup` when it gets instantiated.

If I remove the offending line (instantiation of the `namesByGroup` object) then I get an error when it tries to push to it as it's not been instantiated. How can I push to `namesByGroup`only the actual values and not have an empty entry at index 0?

Comment: Why not just do `this.namesByGroup = [];`? Don't understand your logic though. Seems weird to push the same array over and over.

Comment: You even commented the line where you're adding that empty array. Why don't you ... don't do that instead? Just the way you set up `groupNames`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen - that shows me an error 'Property 0 is missing in type '[ ]' but required in type '[string[ ]]'.

Comment: Did you mean `string[][]` instead of `[string[]]`? The former is an array of string arrays, the latter is an array with a single string array in it, which excludes an empty parent array.

Comment: @VLAZ - that was it. Much appreciated! Add it as an answer if you want and I will mark as the answer

Comment: @sr28 no need, seems like a typo.